# Multiselect drop down checkbox sending only first value

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox

I am trying to create a multiselect drop down list and have created one with this plugin [multiselect](http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/multiple-select/#the-basics1). I created the form :

```
<form action="test1.php" method="post">
 <div class="input select">
 <label for="multiselect">Select employee :</label>
 <select name="data[]">
<option value="1">Umananda Deva Sarma</option>
<option value="2">Bhabesh Sarmah</option>
<option value="3">Manika Goswami</option>
<option value="4">Mridusmita Buragohain</option>
<option value="5">Chinmayee Nath</option>
<option value="6">Urmila Brahma</option>
<option value="7">Kalindra Barman</option>
<option value="8">Mr.Biman Chandra Gogoi</option>
<option value="255">SHRI PHANIDHAR NATH</option>
<option value="256">RANJAN KR. BORA</option>
<option value="257">BASANTA PHUKAN</option>
<option value="258">BHUSAN CH.HIRA</option>
<option value="259">MRINAL KR.BHUYAN</option>
</select></div>      </div>  

<input type="submit" />

</form>
```

But after selecting multiple options when I submit the form , the `var_dump()` shows `data` element contsins onle the first value ! Why the array is not generating ?

Comment: how u are getting the values on the server side ? please add that code as well.

Comment: Looks like you might need the `multiple="multiple"` attribute on the `select` element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add it like this

```
<select name="data[]" multiple="multiple">
```

Answer (score 2):

The select tag should have attribute multiple e.g.

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="data[]">
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at below change of your code:

```
<select name="data[]" multiple="multiple">
```

AND

```
<script src="jquery.multiple.select.js"></script>
<script>
    $('select').multipleSelect();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code...

```
<head>
    <link href="multiple-select.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
<form action="test1.php" method="post">
 <div class="input select">
    <label for="multiselect">Select employee :</label>
    <select multiple="multiple" name="data[]">
        <option value="1">Umananda Deva Sarma</option>
        ...
        <option value="259">MRINAL KR.BHUYAN</option>
    </select>
 </div>
 <input type="submit" />
</form>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.multiple.select.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('select').multipleSelect();
    </script>
</body>
```